# Laravel - clean code and build before deployment

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel web app that is ready to be deployed for production. What I want to do is to clean the code and build the package before pushing it live. All the css and js files need to be combined into one and minified.

I expect Laravel to have something like `grunt build` when developing with NodeJs and AngularJs, but seems like there's not.

Does anybody have done this with Laravel before?

Answer (score 0):

The next version of Laravel, Laravel 5, will have [gulpjs](http://gulpjs.com/) support built into it. As for now, Laravel, doesn't come with any css/js build tools. In my applications, I install gulpjs into the app folder using `npm install gulp`. From there I can just run `gulp` as part of my build process.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does not by default come with a development environment in regards to CSS, JavaScript, and other frontend stuff. Therefor, it won't come with a [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) setup out of the box. You'd have to build your own.

Here is a nice article about doing this: http://blog.elenakolevska.com/using-grunt-with-laravel-and-bootstrap/.

[Laravel homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead#included-software) comes with some of these software bits and pieces already installed, but not configured.